# Find if there is an exponent recursively

Tags: python

I need to write a function that takes 2 parameters base and number.
The function returns `True` if there is an exponent that gives me the number `base ** exp == number` or `False` otherwise.

**Examples:**

```
check_is_power(2, 16) -> True  # because you have a valid exp here (4)
check_is_power(3, 17) -> False # because there is not a whole positive number as an exp
```

**important:**
I can use only these functions to solve this:

```
def add(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    return x + y


def subtract_1(x: int) -> int:
    return x - 1


def is_odd(n: int) -> bool:
    return n % 2 == 1


def divide_by_2(n: int) -> int:
    return n // 2
```

This is what I tried:

```
def check_is_power(base: int, number: int) -> bool:
    if number == base:
        return True
    
    return check_is_power(base, divide_by_2(number))
```

Now, I know I have problems with this code but That's my start position and I would like help to finish this. Thanks!

Comment: If the list of functions you're restricted to includes stuff like `add` and `subtract_1`, are you even allowed to use the `==` operator?

Comment: `exp` always exists and is `exp=log(number)/log(base)`, unless `base` or `number` are zero.

Comment: I think the OP wants `exp` to be restricted to the positive integers, those this is only mentioned in the comments in the example code and is not made clear in the question @Colim

Comment: Why does the first function (`add`) take *floats* as arguments, when it looks like all involved numbers are integers, and none of the other functions can produce  floats.

Comment: Well, the asker is silent. Moving on.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
Work only with integers and positives number

```
def add(a, b) :
    return a + b

def subtract_1(x):
    return x - 1

def mul(a, b) :
    if b == 1:
        return a
    if(b == 0):
        return 0
    return add(mul(a, subtract_1(b)), a)

def exp(a, b) :
    if a == 0 and b == 0:
        return -1 #should be NaN
    if b == 1:
        return a
    if(b == 0):
        return 1
    return mul(exp(a, subtract_1(b)), a)


def check_is_power(base, number):
    e = 0

    if base == 0 and number == 0:
        return True
    if base <= 0 or number <= 0:
       return False

    while True:
        r = exp(base, e)
        if r == number:
            return True
        if r > number:
            break
        e = add(e, 1)
    return False


print(check_is_power(15, 170859375))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not see a restriction on allowing one to change the sign of a value from positive to negative, following is a very simple block of code that appears to provide the necessary results.

```
def add(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    return x + y

def is_exponent(x,y):
    a = 0
    b = y
    c = -x          # No mention of not allowing changing the sign of the base to effectively allow subtraction
    while b > 0:
        b = add(b,c)
        a = a + 1
    
    if b < 0:
        return False
        
    elif b == 0 and a == x:
        return True
        
    elif b == 0 and a < x:
        return False
        
    else:
        return is_exponent(x,a)
    
while True:
    base = int(input("Enter base "))
    value = int(input("Enter value to check "))
    
    if (is_exponent(base, value)):
        print(value, "is an exponent of", base)
    else:
        print(value, "is not an exponent of", base)
        
    choice = input("Do you want to check another pair (y/n)? ")
    if choice != 'y':
        break
```

All that is needed is the addition function along with recursively calling the "is_exponent" function.

Testing this out with a few different base numbers seemed to hold together.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Exponent$ python3 Exponent.py 
Enter base 6
Enter value to check 36
36 is an exponent of 6
Do you want to check another pair (y/n)? y
Enter base 25
Enter value to check 625
625 is an exponent of 25
Do you want to check another pair (y/n)? y
Enter base 25
Enter value to check 125
125 is not an exponent of 25
Do you want to check another pair (y/n)? y
Enter base 17
Enter value to check 4913
4913 is an exponent of 17
Do you want to check another pair (y/n)?
```

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of the exercise.